# Integral of $\sin x \cdot \cos x$

Tags: integration

I've found 3 different solutions of this integral. Where did I make mistakes? In case there is no errors, could you explain why the results are different?

$ \int \sin x \cos x dx $

1) via subsitution $ u = \sin x $
$ u = \sin x; du = \cos x dx \Rightarrow \int udu = \frac12 u^2 \Rightarrow \int \sin x \cos x dx = \frac12 \sin^2 x $

2) via subsitution $ u = \cos x $
$ u = \cos x; du = -\sin x dx \Rightarrow -\int udu = -\frac12 u^2 \Rightarrow \int \sin x \cos x dx = -\frac12 \cos^2 x = -\frac12 (1 - \sin^2 x) = -\frac12 + \frac12 \sin^2 x $

3) using $  \sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x $

$ \int \sin x \cos x dx = \frac12 \int \sin 2x = \frac12 (- \frac12 \cos 2x) = - \frac14 \cos 2x = - \frac14 (1 - 2 \sin^2 x) = - \frac14 + \frac12 \sin^2 x  $

So, we have:
$$ \frac12 \sin^2 x \neq -\frac12 + \frac12 \sin^2 x \neq - \frac14 + \frac12 \sin^2 x  $$

Comment: Ahh! I **always** give this problem in my first year calculus course.

Comment: $+C$... ${}{}{}$

Comment: $*$ is usually used for [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) in this context. I removed it.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Didn't I?

Comment: @Inceptio Check the edit history. I edited the body; you edited the title.

Comment: As trigonometric integrals go, this is a relatively mild example of differences in the numerical constant term.  With some more complicated integrands, alternative integration techniques can give rather different-_looking_ functions that require the use of trig identities to show that the anti-derivatives really only differ by a constant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  A question I often get from students after they've seen a textbook answer for a general anti-derivative is "What happened to the $\frac{1}{2}$?" (or whatever other numerical constant).  I present one or another example in lecture of an integration in which the arbitrary constant $C$ "swallows" the fixed numerical term.

Comment: See also: [two integrals, differ by a constant?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135723/integral-of-sin-x-cos-x-using-two-methods-differs-by-a-constant)

Comment: @amWhy, the related questions you cite include two seemingly contradictory integrals, while this includes three.  This one should be kept as canonical and the others closed.

Answer (score 8):

Antiderivatives are only unique up to adding a constant ('of integration'). If you were to stick limits in your integrals then you'd always get the same number.

Comment: Oh, yes. I checked it with 0 and \pi/2 and those 'strange' fractions deducted each other. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Note: You are calculating **indefinite** integral and constants can be anything(they may differ). In fact the general solution to that would be just $C+\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2}$

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{d\{f(x)+c\}}{dx}=f'(x)$$ for any arbitrary constant  $c$

$$\implies \int f'(x)dx=f(x)+d $$ for any arbitrary constant  $d$

So, in indefinite integral we can get answers which differ by some constant

Answer (score 5):

A primitive is *unique* **up to a constant**