# Why can't I make the substitution $ u = \sin (ax + b) $ to evaluate $ \int \sin (ax + b) \cos (ax + b) dx$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $ \int \sin (ax + b) \cos (ax + b) dx$?

To do this, I started of by substituting $ u = \sin (ax + b) $. That made $ du = cos (ax + b) \cdot a $ and wrote the integral as $ \frac 1a \int u \ du $ to get the final answer as: $$ \frac 1{2a} \sin^2 (ax + b) $$
This answer however, is wrong. My textbook uses a different method and arrives at a different answer. I understand how to arrive at the (right) answer but I want to know why I can't get the same answer by substitution here.

My textbook starts off by rewriting the expression as $ \frac {\sin 2 (ax + b)}{2} $ and then substitutes $ 2 (ax + b) = u $ to get this answer: $$ - \frac { \cos 2 (ax + b) } {4a } $$

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: What you found is indeed an antiderivative of $\sin(ax+b)\cos(ax+b)$.

Comment: They used the identity $\sin(2u)=2\sin(u)\cos(u)$

Comment: The answers differ by a constant (the "C" that you omitted).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: @coreyman317 & David -- Oh, I missed to see that anti-derivatives can differ by a constant! Thanks!

Comment: $\sin^2(ax+b)=\dfrac{1-\cos(2(ax+b))}2$; the $1/2$ gets absorbed in the arbitrary constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral of $\sin x \cos x$ using two methods differs by a constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135723/integral-of-sin-x-cos-x-using-two-methods-differs-by-a-constant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$1-\cos2(ax+b)=2\sin^2(ax+b)$$

So the textbook gives almost the same as your outcome and the difference is constant.

That is allowed because to be found is an antiderivative (not an integral).

Answer (score 2):

The other method probably is that $\int \sin (ax+b) \cos (ax+b) \ dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \sin (2ax+2b) \ dx= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2a}(-\cos(2ax+2b))+c=\frac{1}{4a}(2 \sin^2(ax+b)-1)+c)= \frac{1}{2a} \sin^2(ax+b)+c$

using $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$ and putting $-\frac{1}{4a}$ inside the constant

Answer (score -1):

You can solve with the substitution
u=sin(ax+b) then, 
du=acos(ax+b)dx so,
∫sin(ax+b)cos(ax+b)dx=∫(u/a)du=(u^2)/(2a)=sin^2(ax+b)/(2a)
which is same with your answer-1/4a